# instantiate a class implementing a generic interface using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I have the following in a business logic assembly:

```
public class BusinessEntity
{
    ...
}

public class Customer : BusinessEntity
{
    ...
}

public interface IEntityManager <T> where T : BusinessEntity
{
    T SaveData(T oData);
}

public CustomerEntityManager : IEntityManager <Customer>
{
    Customer SaveData(Customer o)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I am forced to load the above assembly (due to a couple of obvious reasons) in my current project through reflection and instantiate `CustomersEntityManager`.  Imagine that I am writing a method as follows:

```
public class EntityFactory
{
  public static IEntityManager<BusinessEntity> GetManagerInstance(string EntityName)
  {
     var asm = GetAssembly(); // imagine that I loaded the assembly somehow
     EntityName = "Customer"; // just imagine
     object o;     
     // DO NOT KNOW WHAT TO WRITE HERE.
     return o as IEntityManager<BusinessEntity>; // this needs to be an instance of CustomerEntityManager.
  }
}
```

I have the option to modify business assembly. But the instance creation needs to be in my current project and I have to load the business assembly using reflection. All the data types will be known only at run-time.

I may be missing some fundamental things or probably doing wrong coding. Please help me out on this.

UPDATE:

Followed "driss" suggestion, like following:

```
string fullTypeName = "Your.Namespace." + EntityName + "EntityManager";
object o = Activator.CreateInstance(asm.FullName, fullTypeName);
```

Looks like it created the instance. However, it ended up with an error:

> Cannot cast 'o' (which has an actual type of 'CustomerEntityManager') to 'IEntityManager'

when the following statement is getting executed:

```
return o as IEntityManager<BusinessEntity>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to construct the full type name somehow, so that you can get the `Type` instance representing the type. You might decide that the type name relies on a convention, such that you could find the full type name as:

```
string fullTypeName = "Your.Namespace." + EntityName + "EntityManager";
object o = Activator.CreateInstance(asm.FullName, fullTypeName);
```

Then it is just a matter of calling Activator.CreateInstance, as you see.

However, I would highly recommend you looking into using an IoC framework for solving this problem.

**Re: your comment:**

You can't cast CustomerEntityManager to IEntityManager, because that is not what it implements - it only implements IEntityManager. If the cast was allowed, type safety would be broken (you could pass in a BusinessEntity, when the implementation clearly expects a Customer, or, that is at least what the contract says. (Co/contra variance can't save you here because T goes both in and out of IEntityManager).

Comment: driis, I get the error Cannot cast 'o' (which has an actual type of 'CustomerEntityManager') to 'IEntityManager<BusinessEntity>' when the statement "return o as IEntityManager<BusinessEntity>" is getting executed.

Comment: Don't you want IEntityManager<Customer> ? Because that is what CustomerEntityManager implements.

Comment: I would love, if I could.  But, I don't have direct access to "Customer" datatype (loading assembly through reflection) in calling project.  I guess, I will not be able to declare a variable of type "IEntityManager<Customer>" (due to assembly reference).

Comment: driss, Thank you for your guidance.  Will "Unity" framework of Microsoft's PnP will be of any help in my situation?

Comment: Yes, Unity is an IoC framework that will help you inject your dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about using low-level reflection at your own, a lot of not very convenient work. Use an IoC framework if you can, i.e. [StructureMap](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/). With StructureMap you'll just need to create a Registry that knows all the dependencies (such as `CustomersEntityManager` is our implementation for `IEntityManager<Customer>`). It looks more less like that:

```
For<IEntityManager<Customer>>().Use<CustomersEntityManager>()
```

And now if you ask your StructureMap container for an implementation of `IEntityManager<Customer>`, you'll get `CustomersEntityManager`:

```
ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IEntityManager<Customer>>(); // will return instance of CustomersEntityManager
```

If you don't know the requested type at compile time, you can ask for the entity manager using plain `Type` instance:

```
string entityName = "Customer";
Type entityType = Type.GetType(entityType);
Type requestedType = typeof(IEntityManager<>).MakeGenericType(new[] { entityType });
ObjectFactory.GetInstance(requestedType); // will also return CustomersEntityManager instance
```

Registry can be defined in your assembly, without touching the business assembly.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  Is there any Microsoft's PnP implementation of such?

Comment: Yes, it's called Unity - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff663144.aspx - it should generally be able to do the same, but you'll have to read on your own as I don't know Unity very well.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [`Activator.CreateInstance()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d133hta4.aspx)

```
Object o = Activator.CreateInstance (asm.FullName, EntityName );
```

will give you an instance of the `Customer`. I'm not sure how you would go from `Customer` to `CustomerEntity` but I'm sure you can work that part out.