# Instantiate generic type by reflection

Tags: c#, generics

Let's imagine I have instantiated generic type by Activator.CreateInstance. Is there any way to cast it to ISomeInterface if I don't have T in compile time (but I have it as Type instance)?

Here is a sample:

```
public static IPropertyAssertions<T> ShouldHave<T>(this T subject)
{
    var implementedInterfaces = subject.GetType().GetInterfaces();
    foreach (var interfaceType in implementedInterfaces)
    {
        if (!interfaceType.IsGenericType)
            continue;

        var genericType = interfaceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
        if (genericType == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
        {
            var genericTypeArg = genericType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

            var collectionPropertyAssertionsType = typeof (CollectionPropertyAssertions<>);

            Type makeme = collectionPropertyAssertionsType.MakeGenericType(genericTypeArg);

            return (IPropertyAssertions<ToDo: specify argument type here>) Activator.CreateInstance(makeme);
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

So I have extension method which can be called on `IEnumerable<T>`. In this case I would like to return not `CollectionPropertyAssertions<IEnumerable<T>>` but `CollectionPropertyAssertions<T>` where T is type of enumeration element.

Comment: Ever tried to cast it to ISomeInterface? Don't see the real question here? Where is your problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [instantiate a class implementing a generic interface using reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417068/instantiate-a-class-implementing-a-generic-interface-using-reflection)

Comment: Where is the problem? Just cast the result to `IPropertyAssertion<T>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You won't be able to *cast* to it, no - you have to cast to a type which is known at compile-time... half the point is to then be able to use the specific members of that type.

Some scenarios you may want to consider:

- If you want to call a generic method which needs an `ISomeInterface<T>` as a parameter, you could call this via reflection or use dynamic typing
- If you want to call members which don't rely on `T` anyway, you might want to consider creating a non-generic base interface which `ISomeInterface<T>` extends - then you can just cast to the non-generic interface.

If that doesn't cover what you're trying to do, please provide more details.

EDIT: In this case you *do* know `T` because you're in a generic method - so you only need to cast to `IPropertyAssertions<T>`.

Comment: I have added details to the question

Comment: @Idsa: In this case it's easy - you're in the middle of a generic method, so you know `T` already. Just cast and return.

Comment: My input T is of type IEnumerable<T1> and I want to return CollectionPropertyAssertions<T1>, not CollectionPropertyAssertions<T>

Comment: @Idsa: But you've *declared* that you'll return an  `IPropertyAssertions<T>`... so that's all you need to cast it to. All you're trying to do is satisfy the return statement, right?